# Purge postgres database using perl

Tags: perl, postgresql

I have a Postgres purging script in bash where I used to run multiple commands on different tables i.e.

- copy data to temp table. i.e.
  table1 -> temp_table1
- delete data from original table
  based on the temp tables.

for both the above steps, for each table I am connecting to the database. Is there a way to connect to database at once and execute the above steps on different tables using Perl.

Comment: Why do you need the temp table at all? Couldn't you just use the SELECT statement you use to populate the temp table, as a subselect to the DELETE statement? That will probably be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $auth, \%attr);
$dbh->do($statement1);
$dbh->do($statement2);
```

See the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) docs for more details.